# The external link of script and stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Recently, I have encounter some problem while developing web application.Here is the situcation:

```
<script src="/path/to/local/js/file"></script>
```

The code above is common to include a external javascript file from the local directory.
But recently I found a difference when the html  file which the **script** tag is included play a different role in application.

1.When the html file is standalone,the external script work fine.All the defined variable and function could use in main html file.

2.However, when the html file is require by another file. In my case the

> electron main.js. The variable still can be accessed in html file,and the function defined still could recognized by the html file. But the operation inside the function can not be executed. Etc:The function defined is noted but not executable.

I know the electron is a node.js environment. And node.js is server side code. Regular javascript is client side code. So when html file is require by electron main process, is the code in html still have a clear side bournary. And why the external file can not work correctly in this situcation.                    ---Main problem is described, not enough time,edit later.

Comment: You say that "The variable still can be accessed in html file,and the function defined still could recognized by the html file", which shows the script tag is working. What makes you think the "function defined is noted but not executable"? How are you calling the funciotn and what is the expected outcome that isn't happening

Comment: This problem is weird. Maybe I test it later and tell the detail. What I am confused now is: In electron env. We can use "require()" which is the server side code. But actually in the "indexhtml", which is  a client side javascript's place. What is the difference? And  from my recollection, as a part of electron app, the html file can not require external http source with fully function which single html could. Once I try to use a "js" source,but turned out I should import it as a node-module otherwise it can not fetch by network request. Why html in two situcation behave so different.

Comment: Electron let's you use node things, have a read https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app